# Contact us about designs for FrameLayout, ScrollView and BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, bottomnavigationview

**When forming the ui, the scrollview was cut off and asked for a solution.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EmuJ.png)

This is code.

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack"
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
             <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical">

              ....
             </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/main_bnv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#000000"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/menu_selector_color"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/menu_selector_color"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            app:menu="@menu/navi_menu">
    
        </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
    </FrameLayout>
```

As you can see, BottomNavigationView overlaps with ScrollView and covers it. Is there a solution at a time like this?

Comment: can u share the entire layout?

Comment: Whats wrong with your question title ?

Answer (score 0):

assuming your `BottomNavigationView` is fixed and visible always on the bottom: you can exchange `FrameLayout` to `LinearLayout` with `vertical` orientation

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorBlack"
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
... rest of code
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the main layout from FrameLayout to RelativeLayout and give RelativeLayout height to match_parent and also change ScrollView height to match_parent. And put ScrollView above of BottomNavigationView. Hope it will work.